# How to write vbs command "d:\bos\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath d:\bos\data\db" in windows?

Tags: windows, node.js, mongodb, vbscript

My OS: Windows Server 2008

I just want to create a vbs to make my mongodb run automatically once server reboots. My mongod.exe is in the folder:

d:\bos\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe
My mongodb data is in the folder:
d:\bos\data\db

I try to write the vbs like this:

```
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'this one for my nodejs service, and it works
ws.Run "CMD /C supervisor ""E:\Inetpub\wwwroot\bos\app.js"""  
ws.Run "CMD /C d:\bos\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath d:\bos\data\db"
```

And I also try to install the mongodb as Windows services, and it doesn't work at all. 
    d:\bos\mongodb\bin>mongod.exe --install --logpath d:\bos\mongodb\logs\MongoDB.Log 
    -- dbpath d:\bos\data\db --directoryperdb --serviceName MongoDB 
    --serviceDisplayName MongoDB

It doesn't work, could anybody help me please? Thanks in advance!

Best Regards

ShengXing Chi

Comment: I would be looking into why installing the service doesn't work, rather than write a script to do it myself. Failing that, can you not use Task Scheduler to launch MongoDB on system startup?

Comment: Thanks @Jobbo I just typed the command line: "mongod.exe --install --logpath d:\bos\mongodb\logs\MongoDB.Log -- dbpath d:\bos\data\db --directoryperdb --serviceName MongoDB --serviceDisplayName MongoDB" and press enter, but nothing feedback, it just jump to the "d:\bos\mongodb\bin>" again in the console window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should be ashamed of trying to get away with a 'problem description' like "it does not work" twice!
2. The first "it does not work" may well be explained by the "bin>mo" instead of "bin\mo" in your command. Or did you not **copy** it, but typed it in from memory?
3. To troubleshoot the second "it does not work" you should:

wtf

- execute the command from a console (fix errors until it succeeds)
- think about permissions (console user vs script user)
- use `ws.Run "%comspec% /K d:\bos...` in your script
- think about 64/32 bit issues

Comment: Hey Horner, Thanks for your quick answer.
I execute the command from a console, and it works.
    CMD /C d:\bos\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath d:\bos\data
\db